# Calling Fragment Method from Activity in Swipeable Tab Views

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, swipe

I've been working on a project that has swipeable views with tabs.

The tabs exist as fragments. I want to run a fragment method from the main activity on a periodic basis.

To run the methos, I dont' have the ID for the fragment. I read in other posts that:

```
 String tag = "android:switcher:" + TabActivity.this.viewPager.getId() + ":" + "0";
 Tab1Fragment fragment = (Tab1Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
 fragment.someMethod();
```

will return the fragment I desire, which happens to be the zero-th or first tab. However, running this code returns a nullpointer exception.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, at some point you must have:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.framelayout, new SomeXYZFragment(), "some_xyz_fragment");
ft.commit();
```

Add the line:

```
fm.executePendingTransactions();
```

after the line `ft.commit();`

Try this. It should work.

Comment: I solved it myself by sending an intent with a broadcast receiver to update the fragments(which was what I wanted to do in the first place). It just seemed less messy. But this works too. I've tried it :)

Comment: great! I'm happy you could solve the problem on your own ... although sending an `Intent`via a `BroadcastReceiver` to update the `Fragment`s is *less* messy than *this* ?? O_O

Comment: :D Yeah, in a sense. Because I was able to use the broadcast receiver for other things that I needed to implement.